# python setuptools installs package in different directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

```
from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools

setup(name = 'my_project_name',
      version = '0.0.1',
      description = 'My project',
      py_modules = ['main'],
      packages = ['generated'],
      python_requires = '>=3.5',
      install_requires = [
         'requests>=2.20.0',
         'grpcio>=1.48.2',
         'grpcio-tools>=1.48.2' ],
      )
```

Now I do `python setup.py sdist` and it successfully builds package and places in dist/my_project_name-0.0.1.tar.gz in the current directory.

However when I install it with `pip install dist/my_project_name-0.0.1.tar.gz`, it does install the package in $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (which is fine, I don't run it as root), but in two different pieces:

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/main.py
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/generated/*
```

I was expecting that both main.py and generated/ will go under lib/python3.6/site-packages/my_project_name/. Is there a way to do what I want, or this is a `python` way?

Will appreciate helpful advices!

Comment: Well, `py_modules=['main']` says that you want people to do `import main`.

Comment: The source layout dictates the result. Move `main.py` into `generated`, don't use `py_modules`.

Comment: @TimRoberts, appreciate feedback. How do I declare my script in setup.py, if I don't want it to be imported?

Comment: @phd, I'd like to keep them separate, `generated/*` is populated by auto-generated python code, while main.py is handwritten and is importing from `generated/*`

Comment: @Mark "*I'd like to keep them separate*" Then they will be separate in `site-packages`.